# Pagination loop javascript jquery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops, pagination

I need to fix a pagination that is showing all the numbers once
[click to see the pagination I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFDcl.png)

I need to transform it into a pagination like this:

`<< < 1 2 3 4 5 6 7... 50 > >>`

`<< < 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ..60 > >>`

I am researching and testing for 2 days, but nothing works.

```html
<?php if ($num_pages > 1): ?>
<div class="paginador">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="first">Inicio</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="previous">Anterior</a>
  <?php for($i=1; $i<=$num_pages; $i++): ?>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-index page-<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></a>
  <?php endfor; ?>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next">Próximo</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="last">Último</a>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

```js
  $('.paginador .page-index').on('click', function() {
    var classe = $(this).attr('class');
    classe = classe.replace('page-index ', '');
    $('tr.comprovante-pages').hide();
    $('tr.' + classe).show();
  });

  $('.paginador .first').on('click', function() {
    $('tr.comprovante-pages').hide();
    $('tr.page-1').show();
  });

  $('.paginador .last').on('click', function() {
    $('tr.comprovante-pages').hide();
    $('tr.last-page').show();
  });
```

How can I increment this code to transform this pagination, ans the next and previous button aren't work too.

Comment: Pagination is a serious task, if you want it done right. It is not a one line answer. Furthermore what you are asking for is more along the lines of "rewrite/write" this for me rather then "i got an issue with this". Try to solve it yourself, programming is a thinking job not a typing one, if you run into issues that are more specific, post about it and we can help. You are on the right track, just do some thinking and reading about it.

Comment: ok.. i'm just tying to get some help here, but thanks...

Comment: First result in google search is a video that explains what you need to do, but I understand it requires a lot of prior knowledge. My point is, you got to do some reading/research on the topic, its not as simple as writing some small function. There are many ways to go about it as well, its not a one solution fits all. Check out some videos or written guides.

Comment: take a look to this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/pagination-function/